# Two Dimensional Kinematics

Tags: mechanical-engineering, dynamics

Attempting this kinematics question but not really understanding if what I'm doing is right or completely wrong. Should I be starting by finding Vp? Any help appreciated. Not an assignment, just practicing.

[image: Question]
[image: Attempt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us work out the geometric relations first and then do the kinematics.  I will follow a purely algorithmic approach to show the details.  You can arrive at the same result from trigonometric relations.

Let us choose a fixed coordinate frame that has its origin at A, with the three unit vectors $\mathbf{E}_1 = (1, 0, 0)$, $\mathbf{E}_2 = (0, 1, 0)$, and $\mathbf{E}_3 = (0, 0, 1)$ where $\mathbf{E}_1$ is along AB, $\mathbf{E}_2$ is perpendicular to AB (in the plane ABP), and $\mathbf{E}_3$ is perpendicular to the plane ABP.

The position vectors of the three points are
$
  \mathbf{x}_A, \mathbf{x}_B, \mathbf{x}_P \,.
$
Then the direction vectors of interest are
$$
  \mathbf{r}_{BA} = \mathbf{x}_B - \mathbf{x}_A ~,~~
  \mathbf{r}_{PA} = \mathbf{x}_P - \mathbf{x}_A ~,~~ 
  \mathbf{r}_{PB} = \mathbf{x}_P - \mathbf{x}_B \,.
$$
From the figure, if $\theta_A, \theta_B$ are the angles made by PA and PB with AB, and $r_A, r_B$ are the lengths of PA and PB, we have
$$
 \begin{align}
  \mathbf{r}_{BA} &= b \mathbf{E}_1 \\
  \mathbf{r}_{PA} &= -r_A \cos\theta_A \mathbf{E}_1 + r_A \sin\theta_A \mathbf{E}_2 \\
  \mathbf{r}_{PB} &= -r_B \cos\theta_B \mathbf{E}_1 + r_B \sin\theta_B \mathbf{E}_2
  \end{align}
$$
Since $\mathbf{r}_{PB} = -\mathbf{r}_{BA} + \mathbf{r}_{PA}$, we have
$$
  -r_B \cos\theta_B \mathbf{E}_1 + r_B \sin\theta_B \mathbf{E}_2 = -b \mathbf{E}_1 - r_A \cos\theta_A \mathbf{E}_1 + r_A \sin\theta_A \mathbf{E}_2
$$
or
$$
  \begin{align}
  -r_B \cos\theta_B & = -b - r_A \cos\theta_A \\
  r_B \sin\theta_B & = r_A \sin\theta_A
  \end{align}
$$
In matrix form
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos\theta_A & -\cos\theta_B \\
    \sin\theta_A & -\sin\theta_B
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} r_A \\ r_B \end{bmatrix} = 
  \begin{bmatrix} - b \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
The determinant of the $2 \times 2$ matrix is
$$
  D := -\cos\theta_A \sin\theta_B + \sin\theta_A \cos\theta_B = \sin(\theta_A - \theta_B)
$$
Therefore, inverting the matrix, we have
$$
 \begin{bmatrix} r_A \\ r_B \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sin(\theta_A -\theta_B)}
 \begin{bmatrix}
    -\sin\theta_B & \cos\theta_B \\
    -\sin\theta_A & \cos\theta_A
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} - b \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
or
$$
\boxed{
 \begin{align}
   r_A &= \frac{b\sin\theta_B}{\sin(\theta_A -\theta_B)} \\
   r_B &= \frac{b\sin\theta_A}{\sin(\theta_A -\theta_B)}
 \end{align}
}
$$
Plugging in $b = 300$ mm, $\theta_A = 60^\circ$, $\theta_B = 20^\circ$, we have $r_A = 159.6$ mm and $r_B = 404.2$ mm.

Now that we know the geometry, we can do the kinematics.  Choose a rotating frame that has origin
at point A, and the coordinate axes
$$
 \begin{align}
   \mathbf{e}_1 &= \sin\theta_A \mathbf{E}_1 + \cos\theta_A \mathbf{E}_2 \\
   \mathbf{e}_2 &= -\cos\theta_A \mathbf{E}_1 + \sin\theta_A \mathbf{E}_2 = \mathbf{r}_{PA}/||\mathbf{r}_{PA}||\\
   \mathbf{e_3} &= \mathbf{E}_3.
 \end{align}
$$
or, inverting the relation,
$$
 \begin{align}
   \mathbf{E}_1 &= \sin\theta_A \mathbf{e}_1 - \cos\theta_A \mathbf{e}_2 \\
   \mathbf{E}_2 &= \cos\theta_A \mathbf{e}_1 + \sin\theta_A \mathbf{e}_2 \\
   \mathbf{E_3} &= \mathbf{e}_3.
 \end{align}
$$

Then the position vector of P in that coordinate system is
$$
  \mathbf{r}_{PA} = r_A \mathbf{e}_2
$$
and the velocity of P relative to the rotating frame is
$$
  \mathbf{v}_{P/R} = \dot{r}_A \mathbf{e}_2
     = \dot{r}_A \left[-\cos\theta_A \mathbf{E}_1 + \sin\theta_A \mathbf{E}_2\right]
$$
The time derivative of $r_A$ is
$$
  \dot{r}_A = \frac{b\cos\theta_B}{\sin(\theta_A -\theta_B)} \dot{\theta}_B +
  \frac{2b\sin\theta_B\cos(\theta_A-\theta_B)}{\cos[2(\theta_A -\theta_B)]-1}
    (\dot{\theta}_A - \dot{\theta}_B)
$$
or, using $\omega_A = \dot{\theta}_A$ and $\omega_B = \dot{\theta}_B$, 
$$
  \boxed{
  \dot{r}_A = \frac{2b\sin\theta_B\cos(\theta_A-\theta_B)}{\cos[2(\theta_A -\theta_B)]-1}
    \omega_A +
    \left[\frac{b\cos\theta_B}{\sin(\theta_A -\theta_B)} -  
  \frac{2b\sin\theta_B\cos(\theta_A-\theta_B)}{\cos[2(\theta_A -\theta_B)]-1}\right]
    \omega_B
   }
$$
where $\boldsymbol{\Omega}_A = \omega_A \mathbf{E}_3 = \omega_A \mathbf{e}_3$ and $\boldsymbol{\Omega}_B = \omega_B \mathbf{E}_3 = \omega_B \mathbf{e}_3$ are the angular velocities at A and B of AP and BP, respectively.

Plugging in the values that we know, we have
$$
  \dot{r}_A = -190.24 \omega_A + 628.81 \omega_B \,.
$$

At P, the velocity is
$$
  \mathbf{v}_P = \boldsymbol{\Omega}_A \times \mathbf{r}_{PA} +  \mathbf{v}_{P/R}
               = \boldsymbol{\Omega}_B \times \mathbf{r}_{PB}
$$
Therefore, we have
$$
  \begin{align}
  & (\omega_A \mathbf{e}_3) \times (r_A \mathbf{e}_2) + \\
  & \left[\frac{2b\sin\theta_B\cos(\theta_A-\theta_B)}{\cos[2(\theta_A -\theta_B)]-1}
    \omega_A +
    \left[\frac{b\cos\theta_B}{\sin(\theta_A -\theta_B)} -  
  \frac{2b\sin\theta_B\cos(\theta_A-\theta_B)}{\cos[2(\theta_A -\theta_B)]-1}\right]
    \omega_B\right]\mathbf{e}_2 \\
  &= (\omega_B \mathbf{e}_3) \times (-r_B \cos\theta_B \mathbf{E}_1 + r_B \sin\theta_B \mathbf{E}_2)
  \end{align}
$$
Now
$$
  \begin{align}
  \mathbf{e}_3 \times \mathbf{e}_1 &= \mathbf{e}_2 \\
  \mathbf{e}_3 \times \mathbf{e}_2 &= -\mathbf{e}_1 \\
  \mathbf{e}_3 \times \mathbf{E}_1 &= \sin\theta_A \mathbf{e}_3 \times \mathbf{e}_1 -
                                      \cos\theta_A \mathbf{e}_3 \times \mathbf{e}_2
                                    = \sin\theta_A \mathbf{e}_2 + \cos\theta_A \mathbf{e}_1\\
  \mathbf{e}_3 \times \mathbf{E}_2 &= \cos\theta_A \mathbf{e}_3 \times \mathbf{e}_1 +
                                      \sin\theta_A \mathbf{e}_3 \times \mathbf{e}_2
                                    = \cos\theta_A \mathbf{e}_2 - \sin\theta_A \mathbf{e}_1
  \end{align}
$$
Therefore, we have
$$
  \begin{align}
  & -\omega_A r_A \mathbf{e}_1 + \\
  & \left[\frac{2b\sin\theta_B\cos(\theta_A-\theta_B)}{\cos[2(\theta_A -\theta_B)]-1}
    \omega_A +
    \left[\frac{b\cos\theta_B}{\sin(\theta_A -\theta_B)} -  
  \frac{2b\sin\theta_B\cos(\theta_A-\theta_B)}{\cos[2(\theta_A -\theta_B)]-1}\right]
    \omega_B\right]\mathbf{e}_2 \\
  & = \omega_B r_B \left[-\cos\theta_B(\sin\theta_A \mathbf{e}_2 + \cos\theta_A \mathbf{e}_1)
                         +\sin\theta_B(\cos\theta_A \mathbf{e}_2 - \sin\theta_A \mathbf{e}_1)\right]\\
  & = -\omega_B r_B \left[\cos(\theta_A-\theta_B) \mathbf{e}_1 + \sin(\theta_A-\theta_B) \mathbf{e}_2 
                    \right]
  \end{align}
$$
Comparing the components along $\mathbf{e}_1$ and $\mathbf{e}_2$, respectively, we have
$$
   -\omega_A r_A = -\omega_B r_B \cos(\theta_A-\theta_B)
$$
and
$$
  \frac{2b\sin\theta_B\cos(\theta_A-\theta_B)}{\cos[2(\theta_A -\theta_B)]-1}
    \omega_A +
    \left[\frac{b\cos\theta_B}{\sin(\theta_A -\theta_B)} -  
  \frac{2b\sin\theta_B\cos(\theta_A-\theta_B)}{\cos[2(\theta_A -\theta_B)]-1}\right]
    \omega_B = -\omega_B r_B  \sin(\theta_A-\theta_B)
$$

Plugging in $\omega_A = 10$ and the previously computed values of $r_A$ and $r_B$ into the first equation above, we have $\omega_B =$ 5.1555 rad/s.

Therefore, the relative velocity of the slider block is
$$
  \dot{r}_A = -190.24 \omega_A + 628.81 \omega_B  = 1339.4~\text{mm/s} \,.
$$